# "Transparent replacement" of baseclass subobject when complete object is replaced?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, placement-new

Please consider the following code snippet:

```cpp
struct A { int n; };
struct B : A {};
B foo;
new (&foo) B { {42} }; // the new B transparently-replaces foo
int i = foo.n; // is this valid? Does this correctly refer to the new B's A.n ?
```

According to [[basic.life] p8](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#8), the new `B` should transparently replace `foo`. However, the new `B`'s `A`-subobject should not transparently replace `foo.A` because it is a ["potentially-overlapping subobject"](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#7.1), being a base class subobject.

However, is it enough for the enclosing `B` to be replaced for this to be valid?

I have two possible interpretations:

[[basic.life] p8](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#8) says that

> [...] the name of the original object will automatically refer to the new object [...]

thus, `foo` now refers to the new `B`.

[[expr.ref] p6.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#6.2a) says the following about the `.`-member access expression:

> If `E2` is a non-static data member [...] the expression [`E1.E2`] designates the corresponding member subobject of the object designated by the first expression.

Therefore `foo.n` should refer to the new `foo`'s n.

The other interpretation is that `foo.n` is itself, as a whole, considered the "name of the original object" as in the wording (see above) of [basic.life], and it therefore does not refer to the new `int` because that `int` itself is not transparently-replaceable, because its encompassing object, the `A`, is not transparently-replaceable.

Which of these interpretations might be correct, if any?

---

Please keep in mind that this is a [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) question. The question is not so much about whether this practically works, but about the "letter of the law" of the standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first interpretation is correct. In the example:

```cpp
B foo;
new (&foo) B { {42} };
```

`B foo` is transparently replaceable by the new object of type `B` created in its storage, since all requirements in [[basic.life] p8](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#8) are met.
Therefore, the name of the object `foo` now refers to the new object, and:

```cpp
int i = foo.n; // this is now valid, and foo.n refers to the subobject in
               // the new object also named foo
```

##### Why the second interpretation is invalid

`foo.n` can't be considered a name; it is an expression combining multiple names. I don't believe "name" is formally defined by the standard, but the word is strongly associated with *identifier*, as can be seen in [[lex.name]](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name). The way it's used in [[dcl.pre] p4](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.pre#4) suggests that at most `x`, `x::y`, or `...x::y` could be considred names.

Regardless of what a name is, `n` (i.e. `A::n`) is not an object, it is a non-static data member. You can also write `foo.A::n` which makes this more obvious, and is equivalent. [[expr.ref] p6.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#6.2) defines `E1.E2` for an object expression `E1` and a non-static data member `E2`.

##### Conclusion

The transparent replacement is valid. `A::n` is not transparently replaceable, but this is okay, because you replace `B` as  whole, and then look up `A::n` within the replaced `B`.

The subobjects of of `foo` don't have to be individually transparently-replaceable for this to be possible.